# SQL Server 2014 AG Listener

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, listener

I have built a two node SQL Server 2014 Always On cluster on the same subnet.

I need to create two availability groups/listeners in the same instance for two sets of databases. Do I need two separate IP addresses for each listener or one IP address can be shared for both listeners ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a listener creates (permissions must allow, otherwise the entry will be made by the network team) a DNS entry, and has a dependency to an IP address. It logically follows that each listener needs its own IP address, because how else will traffic know where to be directed?

See **Failover Cluster Manager**>[Cluster Name]>**Services and applications**> [Availability Group name]. Under **Server Name** section, the listener name is displayed and shows the **IP Address** underneath, which is reflected as a **Dependencies** entry if you open the properties of the listener name.

If you find a way around it, I'd sure like to know, because it doesn't make sense to me that it would work. Good luck!

Comment: However, if you connect to the listener, you can see all the databases on that server, regardless of if they are part of the availability group you connected to or not.